# System of integer inequalities with fractions

Tags: systems-of-equations, integers, integer-programming

As part of a problem I'm solving, I stumbled across the following system of integer inequalities, for which I cannot seem to find a mathematical method to solve it. The system is as follows:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
B\geq 1\\ 
B\geq -\frac{5}{4}k\\ 
B\leq -\frac{4}{3}k
\end{matrix}\right. \quad\text{or put differently: } \left\{\begin{matrix}
B\geq 1\\ 
k\geq -\frac{4}{5}B\\ 
k\leq -\frac{3}{4}B
\end{matrix}\right.$$
We need to find $B\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k$ can be any integer. E.g. if $B=1$ the system is not valid since we cannot find a $k$ that satisfies all equations. It is not hard to see that $B \geq 12$ is a solution for this problem: $12$ is the first positive integer for which we can find a valid $k$ (in this case $-9$). Any integer $B$ greater than $20$ is also a solution since then the difference between $-\frac{3}{4}B$ and $-\frac{4}{5}B$ is greater than $1$, so we can always find at least one integer $k$ that satisfies the equations.

EDIT: I did not explain where this problem comes from, but $B=4,5,8,9,10$ are also solutions. Only for $B\geq 12$ are all *consecutive* positive integers solutions. That is actually what I'm interested in.

Showing that $B\geq 20$ are *consecutive* solutions is easy (as explained above), but how can you show that $12\leq B < 20$ are also *consecutive* solutions? This is, of course, a toy problem with rather simple fractions, so it would be nice if someone could come up with a rigorous plan to tackle this in case the system gets more complicated. It reminds me somewhat of integer programming... Thanks!

Comment: Just by playing around with some numbers, one could find $x=9, k=-7$ as one solution. Of course there should be infinitely many ...

Comment: Are you sure 12 is the first possible value of $B$? What about $k=-3$?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I wasn't complete in my description. I'll edit my question.